# How to debug which particular Camel Route has a kind of "CPU leak"? Is there a CU metrics per route?

Tags: java, apache-camel

We run a bunch of too different data scraping routes on our Camel instances. And at about 1 week after a start of the Camel run, the CPU resources occupied by the Camel tend to grow and never be released:

[image]

As they reach 100%, the throatling starts and we miss the data.

The first and very simple approach is to set up 1 instances, and and keep an only route in 1 instanc to be observed, while the rest would be in another one, until we define which one causing a problem and then to debug some points/beans inside this particular route. But since the degradation takes week, this approach looks very slow.

Is there a kind of CPU-per-route metric that can make us to estimate which route eats up the CPU resources?

UPD: i'm also monitoring the route metrics, but unfortunately metric s per route just gives me timing, hwhich are not diverged and look increasing/go peaking/go oscilating simultaneously.

[image]

```
sum by(routeId)(rate(CamelMessageHistory_seconds_sum{}[5m]))
```

and

`rate(label_replace({__name__=~"camel_proxy.*count"},"name_label","$1","__name__", "(.+)")[5m:])`

are plotted to prolt Micrometer metrics like that:

```
# HELP CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_max  
# TYPE CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_max gauge
CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_max{camelContext="camel-1",failed="false",routeId="realtime_positioning_raw",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 1.3250687
# HELP CamelRoutePolicy_seconds  
# TYPE CamelRoutePolicy_seconds summary
CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_count{camelContext="camel-1",failed="false",routeId="realtime_positioning_raw",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 868.0
CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_sum{camelContext="camel-1",failed="false",routeId="realtime_positioning_raw",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 15.7921739
```

and

```
# HELP camel_proxy_mqtt_kafka_stream_seconds  
# TYPE camel_proxy_mqtt_kafka_stream_seconds summary
camel_proxy_mqtt_kafka_stream_seconds_count{camelContext="camel-1",} 868.0
camel_proxy_mqtt_kafka_stream_seconds_sum{camelContext="camel-1",} 14.5903913
# HELP camel_proxy_mqtt_kafka_stream_seconds_max  
# TYPE camel_proxy_mqtt_kafka_stream_seconds_max gauge
camel_proxy_mqtt_kafka_stream_seconds_max{camelContext="camel-1",} 1.297158
```

Comment: There are code coverage tools that tell you which methods are being executed.  Those tend to be invasive though so you might want to set up a test server for that.  You might also try taking thread dumps from the JVM directly, and turning on garbage collection logging (gc also requires CPU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user VisualVM (https://visualvm.github.io/) to sample or profile your application, you will find method that consumme CPU.

With camel you can add hawtio (https://hawt.io/), it can help.

Comment: is there a way to make those monitoring results be exported to Prometheus?

Comment: Maybe with hawt.io. But VisualVM sampling or profiling is more a developer tool you need to connect it on live it don't send data.

Comment: I belive I need no static method's execution time distribution, but a dynamical change of it with time to understnd which route starting eating more and more

Comment: Yes but if after one week the method use 90%-100% of CPU it will on top 3 of sampling during 10 minutes, so you'll find it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are using Camel 3.x, I would suggest you two things:

1. Activate MicroProfile metrics so that you can analyse Camel built-in route metrics (by invoking the web service returning data un Prometheus format)
2. Enable exchange pooling to reduce object allocations

Here is an example on how to do it in a CDI environment

```
public class CamelSupport {

    @Inject
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;


    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public final CamelContext createContext() {
        CdiCamelContext context = new CdiCamelContext();
        context.setName("demo");
        ...
        MicroProfileMetricsRoutePolicyFactory mpmrp = new MicroProfileMetricsRoutePolicyFactory();
        mpmrp.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        context.addRoutePolicyFactory(mpmrp); // (1)

        
        context.setExchangeFactory( new PooledExchangeFactory() ); // (2)
        return context;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried with metrics, but they give me only timing metrics, and thus non of the routes look occupying more time.

Comment: ``CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_max{camelContext="camel-1",failed="false",routeId="positioning_raw",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 1.3250687
# HELP CamelRoutePolicy_seconds  
# TYPE CamelRoutePolicy_seconds summary
CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_count{camelContext="camel-1",failed="false",routeId="positioning_raw",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 868.0
CamelRoutePolicy_seconds_sum{camelContext="camel-1",failed="false",routeId="positioning_raw",serviceName="MicrometerRoutePolicyService",} 15.7921739``

Comment: so there is no direct understanding on CPU occupied because of tha timing, despite of for this one I can see the dynamic

Comment: I have updated my question